# className does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have two components. One imports another. But typescript throws an error inside Login.tsx, saying:

> "Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> Props'"

Login.tsx:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import Form from './Form/Form';

import styles from './Login.module.scss';

interface Props {}

function Login({}: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Form className={styles.form}>Form</Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Form.tsx:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function Form({}: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>TESTY</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of doing it is

```
const Login : React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Form className={styles.form}>Form</Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Just because I ran against this issue and used this to help (thanks!), it seems that <Props> was deprecated since & you'd want to use <ScriptProps>.